# Lose/override products after log in

Tags: checkout, cart

today a returning customer has called us to notify that during the checkout the product inside the cart has been substituted by others that haven't been added, so I tried by myself and I have seen that if I have already got some product inside my basket(addced during another logged in session) and I shop while I'm not logged in, then during the checkout, once I log in, the account cart override the current session one.
Is it a common behavior? Is there a way to fix/edit this method?
I'm using varnish and SSL on frontend, cookie domain: www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have previously added products to your cart while logged in and then you return to the site later and login then these previous products are re-added to the cart along side any other products added while not logged in.  So yes this is normal Magento behaviour.  You can disable [persistent shopping cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-a-persistent-shopping-cart) but I believe I'm right in saying cart contents is still remembered in this case.

Comment: The problem is that they don't merge, the logged in cart override the other one

Comment: Core behaviour is to merge - my suggestion would be to investigate customisations to you store which may be stopping this happening.

Comment: Since I have a good number of extension, is there something I should looking for in particular so I can use grep to try to find the source of the problem?

Comment: I would suggest disabling all of your extensions, then test to see if it's now working correctly (if not it might be non extension based changes - diff the core code and look for overridden `Mage` classes under `app/code/local/` and `app/code/community/`). When it's working correctly re-introduce the modules (or other changes) one by one and test each time until functionality breaks.

Comment: Disable/enable all the extension was the method I was trying to avoid, but if there isn't any other way I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Yes it's a bit of a pain, but it at least tracks it down to a particular module. A site note - don't disable the modules in admin, all this does it disable block output, everything else about the module works normally.  You instead need to disable each module by setting `active` to false in each modules `app/etc/modules/` config file. You can also disable all local modules in one go in `app/etc/local.xml` by setting `disable_local_modules` to `true`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error(it looks like to be random), so I have disable all the cookie security check and overrided the default behavior of magento